# Cant get css3 tooltip transition working

Tags: css, css-transitions

http://jsfiddle.net/RUjBh/4/

```
.tooltip{
position:relative
}
.tooltip:hover:after{
    background:#fff !important;
    border-radius: 30px / 120px;
    bottom: -8px;
    box-shadow:0 2px 4px #646464;
    color:#9B9B9B;
    content: attr(title);
    left: 110%;
    padding: 20px 30px;
    z-index: 98;
    width: 240px;
    position:absolute;
    opacity:0.4;font:20px "modernRegular" !important;
    transition: all 1s;
}
.tooltip:hover:after:hover{
    background:#fff !important;
    border-radius: 30px / 120px;
    bottom: -8px;
    box-shadow:0 2px 4px #646464;
    color:#9B9B9B;
    content: attr(title);
    left: 110%;
    padding: 20px 30px;
    z-index: 98;
    width: 240px;
    position:absolute;
    opacity:1;font:20px "modernRegular" !important;
}
```

I tried getting this to work but no luck so far. What am I doing wrong? How can I get this working?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Could you describe the problem you are facing and what have you tried?

Comment: @chepe263 The problem I am facing is trying to make the transition work so that the tooltip fades in. This is the method I tried. There were two more which turned out to be wrong, but this one should work or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your HTML you have an error: You don't close the `a` element.

I made this: http://jsfiddle.net/RUjBh/6/

That's what you want?

**EDIT:** I think this is what you want: http://jsfiddle.net/RUjBh/8/

Cheers, Leo

Comment: Oh ya sorry, was a little typo. Well I am trying to achieve this: http://www.websitecodetutorials.com/code/css/css3-animated-tooltip-cross-browser-demo.php

Comment: With the "triangle" with the border? Or just the rectangular tooltip?

Comment: just rectangular, without the pseudo element.

Comment: Check my post. It was edited with the tooltip that I think you want.